# Why Binder returns null when i bind Service in activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

There is a MainService , it has a data member binder  , and a function member  onBind() which return binder.
In Mainactivity, it has a member binder too, and has a member  conn which class is ServiceConnection, and i override the onServiceConnected() function to asign value to binder.I bind service like this :
bindservice(intent, conn, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE), i post this function in onCreate().However,  the result is that  binder is null.

Comment: Could you post some code? When you bind a service is not binded on the same moment. You have an example on the api [http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: You don't assign any value to `IBinder`. `IBinder` is passed as argument through `onServiceConnected()`. Do you mean this argument is `null`?

Comment: I know what is wrong! Becasue MainService is started by rooy Activity, and it takes a few seconds to initialize. However in root activity onCreate(), the binder is used before MainService created totally.Then onServiceConnected is not called.That is the problem!